Do building supply stores sell small quantities of product to non-professionals?
I am looking to replace my original soffit. The pre-vented hardie soffit looks nice, but Home Depot and Lowes don't carry the 24 inch, and the 16 inch they do carry is not the finish I want.
I don't know much about sourcing materials. The contractors somehow get them... Would a builder supply store be able to order them in less than a full pallet quantity? Would they even entertain an order from a homeowner rather than a builder?

The answer depends entirely on the nature of the supply house. Many do retail sales. Some (a decreasing few, in my experience) do not. Call them or hit their websites.

When I lookup places for Hardie Dealers onthe Hardie website there are many Floor places and Home Depot and Lowes... and a few smaller "building supply" places. Any tips or tricks to finding one that will work with homeowners or is it more of a thing I should just try my luck? The two flooring places would not accept special orders.

Try your luck, probably not the floor places, they will deal mainly with the Hardie tile backer and underlayment boards,  but all the others sound good.

You'd know by now if you just called them rather than going around in circles with us. What's the holdup?

In general, a place catering to the trade - whether electrical, plumbing, lumber, appliance parts or something else - will usually sell to DIYers without a problem. The things to watch out for:

Price - Many places will have a high default price (sometimes 2x the real price). If you set up an account then you automatically get the real price. For $10 of parts (that instead cost you $20) it doesn't matter, but if you order a lot of stuff it can make quite a difference. Most places, but it depends on the salesperson, will either set up an account on the spot if you ask or even, if they are in a good mood and you are a reasonable person (you don't spend 30 minutes asking questions to figure out a $10 item instead of doing the research yourself in advance) will charge it to a "house account" and give you the better price. Don't try to argue "Home Depot has it for less" because their answer will almost always be "so buy it from Home Depot" - and in fact many tradespeople will buy a lot of stuff from Home Depot (or Lowes or whatever) because Home Depot has very good prices on a lot of high-volume items.
Help - These places will often (not always) have very knowledgeable people on staff. But they are generally not interested in walking a newbie DIYer through every little detail. If you want to know which particular widget is compatible with a particular item they are more likely to give a good answer than a big box store. But if you don't even know what kind of widget you need, do that research first.
Items Needing Training/Certification - A classic example is HVAC. There are requirements, at least in the US, before you are allowed to buy refrigerant and related things. Some places will be very careful about this, some won't. But the ones that are careful about this may extend it to a lot more HVAC stuff that can be installed without touching the closed refrigerant system because that is a way of weeding out people who are less knowledgeable and therefore more likely to need extra help (time is money) and/or have excessive returns.


Big box stores can order many products that they don't keep in stock.
(My check showed that HD shows 24" not available but Lowes can order it.)
The best bet is talk to the people at the Pro Desk.  ( They will work with anyone.)  The same is true at most all building supply centers.
None of the products are finished, they must be painted.

Do you think the Pro Desk would be open to work with homeowners (non-contractors, i mean)? Should I expect any difficulty there?

Pro desk will help anybody.  They are there to help Pros with large orders but will help any customer with any product they have.  That's why they are there.  It would be good if you had any product info like the manufacturers model number to help them find what you want.
